# svg animation with css not working on safari

Tags: html, svg, safari, webkit, css-transitions

I am trying to animate a SVG on scroll. It is mostly CSS for the transition. The CSS works well on android and windows but breaks on all Apple devices. I have included the vendor prefixes as well and also checked the CSS compatibility with safari with [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/). All seems to be in order. but I am surely missing something here.

```js
function updateNameClass() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
    $("#myName").addClass("initialsOnly");
  } else {
    $("#myName").removeClass("initialsOnly");
  }
}
$(window).scroll(function () {
  updateNameClass();
});
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dongle:wght@700&display=swap");

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 1000px;
  background-color: #fddad8;
}

.dongle {
  font-family: "Dongle", sans-serif;
}
.nav {position:fixed; top:0; left:0; width:100%;}

nav svg {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 158px;
  height: 42px;
}

nav svg text {
  display: inline-block;
}

#myName text:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1.2s ease, -webkit-transform 0.6s ease;
  transition: opacity 1.2s ease, transform 0.6s ease;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.5s;
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
}

#myName text:nth-child(4) {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1.2s ease, -webkit-transform 0.6s ease;
  transition: opacity 1.2s ease, transform 0.6s ease;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.5s;
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
}

#myName text:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.8s ease;
  transition: transform 0.8s ease;
}

#myName.initialsOnly text:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-30px, 0);
  transform: translate(-30px, 0);
  -ms-transform-origin: right;
  -webkit-transform-origin: right;
  -moz-transform-origin: right;
  -o-transform-origin: right;
  transform-origin: right;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s ease, -webkit-transform 0.6s ease;
  transition: opacity 0.6s ease, transform 0.6s ease;
}

#myName.initialsOnly text:nth-child(4) {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-30px, 0);
  transform: translate(-30px, 0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: right;
  transform-origin: right;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s ease, -webkit-transform 0.6s ease;
  transition: opacity 0.6s ease, transform 0.6s ease;
}

#myName.initialsOnly text:nth-child(3) {
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.8s ease;
  transition: transform 0.8s ease;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-160px, 0);
  transform: translate(-160px, 0);
}

#myName text:nth-child(5) {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

#myName.initialsOnly text:nth-child(5) {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-170px, 0);
  transform: translate(-170px, 0);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 1.2s;
  transition-delay: 1.2s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform 0.6s ease;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out, transform 0.6s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">
    <svg id="myName" class="d-inline-block align-text-top dongle" viewBox=" 0 0 400 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <text x="0" y="74" font-size="132" font-family="dongle">
        <tspan fill="#9B2E27">r</tspan>
      </text>
      <text x="34" y="72" font-size="122" font-family="dongle" fill="#B8726E">atul </text>
      <text x="200" y="74" font-size="132" font-family="dongle">
        <tspan fill="#9B2E27">k</tspan>
      </text>
      <text x="244" y="72" font-size="122" font-family="dongle" fill="#B8726E">eot</text>
      <text x="260" y="72" font-size="152" font-family="" fill="#B8726E">.</text>
    </svg>
   </div>
```

Here is the codepen link: https://codepen.io/ratulkt/pen/ZEmbjGe
Any pointer to improve this is also appreciated. Thank you